# error CS0103: The name 'playfabManager' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started using Unity, to make a small game called flappy duck.
I wanne have an online leaderboard so everyone can beat each others highscore.
I stumbled on this error Assets\scripts\PlayerController.cs(65,9): error CS0103: The name 'playfabManager' does not exist in the current context

I cand cant find anything wrong. BTW i am using a tutorial
from CoCo Code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2RXDso6fWU&t=266s he uses playfab i am trying to
get this working in my own game.
THIS IS THE SCRIPT THAT MAKES THE TEXT DISPLAY THE HIGHSCORE

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HighSScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text HighScore;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        HighScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore").ToString();
    }
}
```

THIS IS THE PLAYFAB MANAGER

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.ClientModels;

public class PlayFabManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Login();   
    }
    void Login()
    {
        var request = new LoginWithCustomIDRequest
        {
            CustomId = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier,
            CreateAccount = true
        };
        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithCustomID(request, OnSuccess, OnError);
    }
    
    void OnSuccess(LoginResult result)
    {
    Debug.Log("Successful login/account create!");
    }

    void OnError(PlayFabError error)
    {
    Debug.Log("Error while logging in/creating account!");
    Debug.Log(error.GenerateErrorReport());
    }
    public void SendLeaderboard(int score)  
    {
        var request = new UpdatePlayerStatisticsRequest
        {
            Statistics = new List<StatisticUpdate>
            {
                new StatisticUpdate
                {
                    StatisticName = "score",
                    Value = score
                }
            }
        };
        PlayFabClientAPI.UpdatePlayerStatistics(request, OnLeaderboardUpdate, OnError);
    }

    void OnLeaderboardUpdate(UpdatePlayerStatisticsResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("succsessfull send leaderboard");
    }
}`
```

LAST IS THIS THE PLAYERCONTROLLER
were the error is based on line 65
I am trying to send the highscore to the leaderboard in playfab.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    Rigidbody2D bird;
    int score = 0;
    bool dead = false;
    int highscore = 0;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bird = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && !dead)
        {
            bird.velocity = new Vector2(0, 6f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
        if (score > highscore)
        {
            highscore = score;
            SendLeaderboard();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", score);
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D()
    {
        dead = true;
        score = 0;
        scoreText.text = "0";
    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "PointTrigger")
        {
            score++;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "PointTrigger")
        {
            score++;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void SendLeaderboard()
    {
        playfabManager.SendLeaderboard(highscore);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in `PlayerController` you wanted to have a

```
[SerializeField] private PlayFabManager playfabManager;
```

and either reference it via the Inspector or at runtime via e.g.

```
private void Awake ()
{
    // Try and get the component if it is attached to the same object as this
    if(! playfabManager) playfabManager = GetComponent<PlayFabManager>();

    // Or try and find it anywhere in the scene
    if(! playfabManager) playfabManager = FindObjectOfType<PlayFabManager>();

    // Or simply create and attach it to the same object as this one
    if(! playfabManager) playfabManager = gameObject.AddComponent<PlayFabManager>();
}
```

---

Or - and in my eyes this would be the more correct solution - the `PlayerFabManager` should **not** be a `MonoBehaviour` at all but rather simply do

```
public class PlayFabManager
{
    public void Login()
    {
        ...  
    }

    ...
}
```

And in `PlayerController` you'd rather do

```
private readonly PlayFabManager playfabManager = new PlayFabManager();

private void Start ()
{
    playfabManager.Login();
}
```